# SQL ORACLE Select the top-N rows using join

Tags: sql, oracle

Find the cats occupying the first **n** places in terms of the total number of mice consumed (cats with the same consumption occupy the same place!) **using the join of the Kocury relation with the Kocury relation**.

[this solution doesn't quite work properly]
When **n=1** there are two cats (Tygrys and Lysy), but should be only Tygrys.

[image: 1]

I have 3 correct solutions but for my 4 one I have ot use JOIN operator or LEFT JOIN or sth related to JOIN:

```
solution 1.
SELECT pseudo, przydzial_myszy + NVL(myszy_extra, 0) "ZJADA"
FROM Kocury K
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT przydzial_myszy + NVL(myszy_extra, 0)) FROM Kocury`enter code here`
      WHERE przydzial_myszy + NVL(myszy_extra, 0) > K.przydzial_myszy + NVL(K.myszy_extra, 0)) < 6
ORDER BY 2 DESC;

solution 2
SELECT pseudo, przydzial_myszy + NVL(myszy_extra, 0) "ZJADA"
FROM Kocury
WHERE przydzial_myszy + NVL(myszy_extra, 0) IN (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT przydzial_myszy + NVL(myszy_extra, 0)
    FROM Kocury
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
  ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 6
);

solution 3
SELECT pseudo, ZJADA
FROM
(
  SELECT pseudo,
    NVL(przydzial_myszy, 0) + NVL(myszy_extra, 0) "ZJADA",
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
      ORDER BY przydzial_myszy + NVL(myszy_extra, 0) DESC
    ) RANK
  FROM Kocury
)
WHERE RANK <= 6;
```

[Kocury relation]

[image: 2]

Comment: Saying "doesn't quite work properly" is not any help.  Do you get an error?  If so, who us the error.  Do you get unexpected results?  If so, show us the results you get and the results you should get.  I strongly recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your edit makes no sense to me, why do you only want one row returned if `n=2`?

Comment: @MatBailie sorry, my bad. I have meant n = 1.

Comment: You're either not showing the real data, or not showing the real query, or not describing the real problem.  Check this out *(proof that your query works for that data)* : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8fa3880d54fed31ae26bf1b1d867ff94  *(This is exactly why sample test data, expected results, etc, are extremely important.  Please actually read the link I gave you in the first comment, it will really help you in the future.)*

Comment: @MatBailie I have uploaded my 3 other solutions. But for my 4 one I have to use Kocury  K1 JOIN (or LEFT JOIN or sth related to this) Kocury K2

Comment: @MatBailie I would rather something like HAVING COUNT(something) <= n. So when n = 2 there should be 2 cats (or more if there are repetitions). As far as I can see in your solution there works HAVING COUNT(something) <= (n-1)

Comment: It's ***your*** code, not mine.  When you specify `COUNT(k2.pseudo) < 1` you get ***one*** cat.  You don't get `n-1` cats, you get `n` cats.  The example with `COUNT(k2.pseudo) < 3` gives four cats ***because two of the cats are tied for third position***...  From your question; `(cats with the same consumption occupy the same place!)`  You're trying to solve a problem that simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @MatBailie In my solution I would like to have JOIN and the n (as a variable that when I change I get a specific amount of records which equal n)

Comment: Here's ***yet another link***, showing that ***all*** the answers give the ***same*** result.  If Solutions 1, 2 & 3 are correct, they're ***all correct***...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e2a48c80284049d7ba217e406d807962

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand column names so I'll suggest a query which is somewhat simpler to understand. Read comments within code. Basically, you'd

- find how many mice each cat got
- rank cats by number of mice (using `dense_rank` analytic function; check `rank` and `row_number` as well)
- finally, return cats who rank the *highest*

---

```
with 
temp as
  (select cat_name,
     sum(mice_consumed) sum_mice
   from cats_mice
   group by cat_name
  ),
rank_cats as
  (select cat_name,
     sum_mice,
     dense_rank() over (order by sum_mice desc) rnk
   from temp
  )
-- finally:
select cat_name,
  sum_mice
from rank_cats
where rnk < 7;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have to use JOIN operator or related one.

Comment: Feel free to join whatever you want. As I said, I don't understand what your table represents nor why you **have to** use a join. I showed you how to **rank** rows you got as a result. If query you wrote returns desired result (partially), then use it as a CTE, perform RANKing on that result set and return only rows that rank the highest.

Comment: @Littlefoot The OP's example is `SELECT x.id, MAX(x.val) FROM data x JOIN data y ON y.val < x.val GROUP BY x.id HAVING COUNT(y.id) < 7`.  In other words, use a join to find out how many rows would come before this row; ranking without window functions.  Considering this as an XY Problem, and that this appears to be homework, I think the OP just needs to find a better teacher.

Comment: Possibly, @Mat; thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MatBailie your solution does not work. The one that I have made is bad because for example when it is n=1 I can see 2 cats (Tygrys and Lysy), but ther should be only Tygrys. There is a problem with Tygrys who has the biggest amount of mices.

Comment: @BartoszZiółkowski - I didn't give a solution, I paraphrased your existing code - Becuase ***you*** didn't explain what it's doing.

Comment: @Littlefoot have uploaded my 3 other solutions. But for my 4 one I have to use Kocury  K1 JOIN (or LEFT JOIN or sth related to this) Kocury K2

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT k.pseudo,
       MAX(k.przydzial_myszy) AS przydzial_myszy,
       MAX(k.myszy_extra) AS myszy_extra,
       MAX(k.przydzial_myszy + COALESCE(k.myszy_extra, 0)) AS total
FROM   Kocury k
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Kocury h
       ON (h.przydzial_myszy + COALESCE(h.myszy_extra, 0)
            > k.przydzial_myszy + COALESCE(k.myszy_extra, 0))
GROUP BY k.pseudo
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT h.przydzial_myszy + COALESCE(h.myszy_extra, 0)) < 3
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Kocury (pseudo, przydzial_myszy, myszy_extra) AS
SELECT 'PLACEK',   67, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RURA',     56, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LOLA',     25, 47   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZERO',     43, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PUSZYSTA', 20, 35   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UCHO',     40, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MALY',     40, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TYGRYS',  103, 33   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BOLEK',    50, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZOMBI',    75, 13   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LYSY',     72, 21   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SZYBKA',   65, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MALA',     22, 42   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RAFA',     65, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PSEUDO | PRZYDZIAL_MYSZY | MYSZY_EXTRA | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | TYGRYS | 103 | 33 | 136 |
> | LYSY | 72 | 21 | 93 |
> | ZOMBI | 75 | 13 | 88 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ded1564c3d982aba136a7808b801091)*